# Linq-to-Entities return list along with average of ratings infor each item

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, aggregate-functions

I am returning a list of restaurants that pulls information from the RESTAURANT, CUISINE, CITY, and STARRATING tables.  I want to get a list of each restaurant with its associated city and cuisine along with the average rating in the STARRATING table.  This is what I have, so far ... Thanks in advance.

```
   RestaurantsEntities db = new RestaurantsEntities();
public List<RESTAURANT> getRestaurantsWRating(string cuisineName, string cityName, string priceName, string ratingName)
{
    var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;
    List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE").Include("STARRATING")
                               where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                               orderby RESTAURANT.REST_NAME ascending
                               select RESTAURANT).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have it looks like `Restaurant` has a `STARRATING` collection. If so, this is what you can do:

```
from r in db.Restaurants
where r.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
orderby r.REST_NAME ascending
select new { 
    Restaurant = r, 
    City = r.CITY,
    Cuisine = r.CUISINE,
    AvgRating = r.STARRATING.Average(rt => rt.Rating) 
}
```

You'd need to give more informations about your classes and associations (preferably a class diagram) if this is not right.

(BTW using capitals for class and property names is not conventional).

Answer (score -1):

First I would wrap your whole code block above in a using statement:

```
using(RestaurantEntities db = new RestaurantEntities())
{
    ...
}
```

This will help with cleanup for the EF context.

The way I would typically do this is if you have control of your database, I would create a view in the database that does this work, add the view to your entity model and query the view.  This simplifies the whole process and offloads the work of the aggregation to the database.

If you don't have control over the database or don't prefer the view technique then I would query using the include technique as you have done and then add a partial class to RESTAURANT (if using model-first) in order to add an AverageRating property and then manually calculate the average for each related STARRATING set of related rows and apply the resultant value to the added property.  You could do this through linq to objects once you have all the data back.  This technique would not scale very well as more data is accumulated unless you are confident you never return but one or a few RESTAURANT instances.  You could use something like:

```
//query data as you have done above...
foreach(RESTAURANT r in result)
{
    if(r.STARRATING.Count() > 0)
    {
        r.AverageRating = r.STARRATING.Average(rating => rating.Value); //.Value is your field name
    }
    else
    {
        r.AverageRating = 0; // or whatever default you prefer...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this method isnt very scalable and should be done using .GroupBy()

Comment: I mentioned it doesn't scale very well.  The View approach is a reasonable way to do this without having to do GroupBy() in the linq query.  I agree that is the right way to get the linq query to return appropriate results, but was assuming there was no target property on the RESTAURANT class to accept the result.